# Change a specific woo-commerce product "add to cart" button to "buy now"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to change a specific product (product_id=13528) "add to cart" button to a Buy Now. Clicking on “Buy Now” button should skip the cart and jumps to the checkout page.

Please help!

Sorry for all the typos.

Answer (score 3):

This will redirect to checkout for the specific product:

```
add_filter ('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');
function redirect_to_checkout($url) {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( isset( $_POST['add-to-cart'] ) ) {
        $product_id = (int)$_POST['add-to-cart'];
        if($product_id == 13528){
            $url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
```

and this will change add to cart text:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_cart_button_text' ); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_cart_button_text' ); 

function custom_cart_button_text($text) {
    global $woocommerce;
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    if($post_id == 13528){
        $text = __( 'Buy Now', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The redirect snippet didn't work for me, or maybe I'm missing something?  The second worked flawlessly though.

Comment: I made a change to get the correct product id, you can try now, it's not tested but should work.